# Socially acceptable term for "job" to use in email

Tags: single-word-requests

The word "job" has some negative baggage attached to it when asking people for things. On a resume or personal website, saying "email here if you want to give me a job" would be considered heavy-handed. More socially acceptable is to use the word "opportunities" which doesn't carry with it such a direct association with money and labor.

I recently purchased a web domain for myself, and in my efforts to organize correspondence I've made a few email addresses for different purposes. I've made *spam@johnsmith.com* for emails which I strongly suspect are of the unwanted variety, *tutoring@johnsmith.com* for my tutoring work, and so on.

I'm currently looking for a term I can use for my "send career opportunities here" email. I've considered:

- *jobs@johnsmith.com* — Heavy-handed
- *careers@johnsmith.com* — Better than *jobs*, but sounds like I'm hiring
- *work@johnsmith.com* — Ugh, I mean it works, but it doesn't sound good
- *opportunities@johnsmith.com* — Not bad, perhaps a bit vague
- *careeropportunities@johnsmith.com* — Clear but a little direct and very wordy

**Any ideas for a term I can use in professional settings to mean "job" that doesn't carry negative connotations and clearly expresses a willingness to pursue new career opportunities without being too overt?**

Comment: _hiring@johnsmith.com_?

Comment: "*Email me here if you want to give me a job*"? I've never seen anything like that used on any website. As far as I'm concerned it's highly unusual. At best, I've seen *Donate* buttons for things like PayPal or other charity funding. In short ***none*** of the synonymous words or phrases you list will do, because *all* of them convey the impression that its an address to which people would send you their resume. (Which you say you don't want, because you're not hiring.) Why would anybody want to ***give*** you a job? Just have a link with something like **Hire Me** that sends them your resume.

Comment: @JasonBassford My wording there was a bit direct so as to press the point, but ultimately that's what I'm going for — A _hire me_ email address that's socially acceptable in a professional environment

Comment: @Tal What I'm saying is nobody uses a generic email address for that purpose. If anybody was interested in hiring you, they would write to your personal email address. The use of different wording for that specific purpose is confusing. There simply ***is*** no socially acceptable generic email address to use for that intent.

Comment: @Tal The best you could possibly do, I think, and neither is a good idea, is the previously mentioned *hireme@johnsmith.com* or *employmentseeker@johnsmith.com*. But both sound like something from a dating site, and they would likely discourage any legitimately interested employers from writing.

Comment: *Job* is not negative at all. *Give me a job* is a crude demand, as you realize.

Comment: hungry@johnsmith.com?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that anything you put for this address will be a bit cumbersome. In the past I've used jobs@, but when I do it again, I'll just leave off the other email address completely and give my main email address. I know that's not the answer you're looking for, but there are benefits in that it sends the message that you're a real person and that you're reachable.

Answer (score 0):

**employment**@[email address].com

No negative connotations as far as I am aware but then again I don't see why the short three-letter word *job*, probably derived from Middle English [*jobben*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/job#Etymology), doesn't work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

**[Designation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/designation)** is a good word to use here.

- *designation@johnsmith.com*

Or try **[occupation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/occupation)**.

- *occupation@johnsmith.com*

I don't think either of these words has any negative connotations.

Answer (score 0):

I would use: pro@johnsmith.com

As for the "email here if you want to give me a job", I'd use: "Feel free to contact at me at this email address for any professional opportunities/matters"